# Looping for como parametro de looping while

Tags: python, python-3.x, loop, python-2.7

Sendo que a lista `cont` teria os valores:

```
cont = ['t','f','f','t','f']
```

Seria possível algo como isso:

```
while(for cont in cont == 'f'):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode colocar uma condição quando for iterar:

```
letras = ['t','f','f','t','f']

for letra in [i for i in letras if i != 'f']:
    print(letra)
```

[`Ver Demonstração`](https://repl.it/Cfzd)

Ou colocar a condição fora do *loop*:

```
letras = ['t','f','f','t','f']

for letra in letras:
    if letra == 'f':
        continue
    print(letra)
```

[`Ver demonstração`](https://repl.it/Cfzd/1)

Answer (score 2):

Sim, mas tente sem o `while`:

```
for letraF in [letra for letra in cont if letra == 'f']:
    print(letraF)
```

Comment: interessante porem a resposta do compilador é `SyntaxError: invalid synta`

Comment: @Nasca Desculpe. Falta de atenção. Veja a nova versão.

Comment: Uma sugestão é usar parenteses em vez de colchetes na exxpressãoque gera o itnerável do `for`: dessa forma, o Python vai gerar um elemento de cada vez a medida que ele for consumido. Com colchetes ele vai executar todo o `for`  interno antes, guardar tudo na memória, e executar o `for`externo depois. 

Na prática, para listas pequenas, e operações sincronas, isso não faz tanta diferença. Para sequências maiores, possivelmente geradas de forma assíncrona, isso já muda.

Comment: @jsbueno Sim. Expressões geradoras são muito legais. :)
Só deixei com _list comprehensions_ mesmo porque seria mais fácil explicar em caso de solicitação de esclarecimento, e porque otimizações desse formato costumam se pagarem mesmo só quando o conjunto de dados é grande, como você disse.